# Error Call a Method of Model in Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Hello im try call a method of my model from my controller, but when try the instance get this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `products=' for #<Class:0x114bc4c50>):
  app/controllers/carts_controller.rb:57:in `calculate_ship'
```

model.rb

```
def self.make_pack
    products.each do |p|
      p.product.length = 16 if p.product.blank?
      p.product.weight = 0.3 if p.product.blank?
      p.product.width = 11 if p.product.blank?
      p.product.height = 6 if p.product.blank?
      @item = Correios::Frete::PacoteItem.new :peso => p.product.weight, :comprimento => p.product.length, :largura => p.product.width, :altura => p.product.height
      while p.quantity > 0
        pacote.add_item(@item)
        p.quantity -= 1
      end
    end
  end
```

and when i call is this the method:

```
Cart.products = buy_cart.line_items
  Cart.make_pack
```

The error is in the first line i dont undertand because what, please someone can help me?

Answer (score 2):

If `product` is defined in `Cart` with `attr_accessor :product`, then `product` belongs to *instances* of `Cart`. It cannot be accessed by the class as `Cart.product`. So your code would need to say something like:

```
my_cart.product = buy_cart.line_items
```

You can define it as a class method as follows:

```
class Cart...
  ...

  self.product=( prod )
    @product = prod
  end

  self.product
    @product
  end

  ...
end
```

Then a reference such as `Cart.product = something` should work.

Comment: Product not has_many products, is this:   has_many :line_items,:dependent => :destroy
I dont undertand what i make wrong

Comment: What is `products` then and how is it defined for the `Cart` model?

Comment: attr_accessor :products some this